# How to make notification text

Tags: java, android

I created an app that reminds the user for everything he needs. The concept is that the user writes what he needs in the `EditText` and when the app sends the notification, the notification text will be replaced from the edittext. Here is the code I have written:
For the mainActivity:

```
package com.example.reminder4;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button notification;
    TextView message;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        notification = findViewById(R.id.notification);
        message = findViewById(R.id.write);
        final String messageStrg = message.getText().toString();


        notification.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                        MainActivity.this
                )
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                        .setContentTitle("New Notification")
                        .setContentText(messageStrg)
                        .setAutoCancel(true);


                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        NotificationActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intent.putExtra("messageStrg", messageStrg);

                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this,
                        0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(
                        Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE
                );
                notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
            }
        });

    }
}
```

For the main_activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">




    <Button
        android:id="@+id/notification"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Notification"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.774" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/write"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="Write Something"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="111dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="255dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And for the NotificationActivity:

```
package com.example.reminder4;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NotificationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notification);

        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.text_view);

        String message = getIntent().getStringExtra("message");
        textView.setText(message);
    }
}
```

When I write something into the edit text and press the button there is nothing appear at the notification text. What should I do?

Comment: If you are using the OS version as above Oreo, you have to create a channel for Notification builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`messageStr` value is empty because its value was set when the activity was created, what you need to do is refer to the `EditText` content in the `onClickListener` and set its content to the notification text

Edit:
And also change the type of message from `TextView` to `EditText`

Comment: You mean that I need to replace `TextView` with `EditText`?

Comment: Yes and also get the content of the EditText inside the onClickListener.

Comment: How can I get the content inside the onClicklistener? Sorry for asking something that is probably easy, but I am new in android programming

Comment: message.getText()
Same as you did before just inside the onClickListener so that you will get the content at the time the button is clicked.